# Ngninx reports 8 active connections even though there are not

Tags: http, unix, nginx

I compiled Nginx 1.2.4 with --with-http_stub_status_module.

When I query Nginx regarding its current status it returns *8 Active connections* which are all *Writing* type:

```
Active connections: 8 
server accepts handled requests
5011178 5011178 5011178 
Reading: 0 Writing: 8 Waiting: 0
```

However there is absolutely no more established connection to my Nginx except the curl I'm performing to get the status.

Any idea why Nginx returns this number of Active connections?

Answer (score 1):

Active connections don't represented number of request to your app. If your app serves some `html` pages then each element like `image`, `css` or `js` (if isn't cached in browser or other user client) will be also requested from your server. So for one `html` pages there can be many active connections.

But... as I know they will be as `Reading` or `Waiting` connections and in your example there are `Writing`. If you are extremely sure that there is only one request from `curl` made by you then check your `nginx` or some `proxy` (if exists) configuration because it's look like client connections aren't closed after some `POST` request or `Uploads`.

Comment: The HTML being served is not containing any image, css or JS, it's only HTML. I'm sure there is no more traffic being served to it. Also I have 2 nodes, one of them is reporting Writing: 8 and the other is reporting Writing: 8. But both does not have traffic. I suspect some caching on that Nginx module.

Comment: One more thing we can do is to examine how do you use stub module, can you paste parts of your configuration when you are using it?

Comment: location /nginx_health {
  access_log off;
  allow 127.0.0.1;
  deny all;
  stub_status on;
} Also restarting Nginx solve the issue. But this is not an acceptable solution.